# I have tried to submit the form in django but only redirection function is working data is not showing in django admin

Tags: python, html, django

My views.py are

```
def login_register(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        first_name=request.POST['first_name']
        last_name=request.POST['last_name']
        email=request.POST['email']
        password=request.POST['password']

        # check for errornous inputs

        #create the user
        myuser=User.objects.create( 
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name
        )
        myuser.save()
        return redirect('shophome')

    return render(request, 'shop/login.html')
```

my urls.py are

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='shophome'),
    path('product-list/', views.product_list, name='product_list'),
    path('product-detail/', views.product_detail, name='product_detail'),
    path('cart/', views.cart, name='cart'),
    path('checkout/', views.checkout, name='checkout'),
    path('my-account/', views.my_account, name='My_account'),
    path('contactus/', views.contactus, name='contactus'),
    path('wishlist/', views.wishlist, name='wishlist'),
    path('login/', views.login_register, name='login_register'),

    
]
```

I have tried to submit the form with post method but its not working.

when i submit the form it should redirect to home page and data should save in django admin but only redirection is working.

Answer (score 1):

to create a user in django, there are some mandatory fields that should be provided with data which are username, email and password, otherwise it will raise error. You can ask user to provide username or concatenate first_name and last_name for username.

```
myuser = User(username=username,
                first_name=first_name,
                last_name=last_name,
                email=email)
myuser.set_password(password)
myuser.save()
```